# Why my form is getting closed when i move the Tab to and fro from the textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code in my TextBox leave event:

```
private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
   double res = (double)x / 100;
   txtAmount.Text = "$" + res.ToString();
}
```

But if move back to the previous control by hitting Shift+Tab and again moving back to the same textbox and then trying to move to other the form is getting closed automatically. Why does this happen?

Comment: You'll have to give us some more code. There is nothing there that would explain what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried catching thrown exceptions, not just uncaught? You can do this in Debug -> Exceptions...

Comment: Only after writing this event i am getting the issue before it works fine

Comment: So you didn't see any exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution

```
      private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strAmnt = string.Empty;
        strAmnt = txtAmount.Text;
        if (strAmnt.Contains(".") && !strAmnt.Contains("$"))
        {

            txtAmount.Text = "$" + strAmnt;
            while (txtAmount.Text.Length - txtAmount.Text.IndexOf(".") <= 2)
            {
                txtAmount.Text += "0";
            }
        }
        else
            if (strAmnt.Contains("$") && !strAmnt.Contains("."))
            {
                Int64 amnt = 0;
                strAmnt = strAmnt.Replace("$", "");
                try
                {
                    amnt = Convert.ToInt64(strAmnt);
                    double amt = (double)amnt / 100;
                    txtAmount.Text = "$" + amt.ToString();
                }
                catch (FormatException ie)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format");
                }
            }
            else
                if (!strAmnt.Contains(".") && !strAmnt.Contains("$"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
                        double res = (double)x / 100;
                        txtAmount.Text = "$" + res.ToString();
                        while (txtAmount.Text.Length - txtAmount.Text.IndexOf(".") <= 2)
                        {
                            txtAmount.Text += "0";
                        }
                    }
                    catch (FormatException ie)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("InvalidFormat");
                    }
                }
        while (txtAmount.Text.Length - txtAmount.Text.IndexOf(".") <= 2)
        {
            txtAmount.Text += "0";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The call to [`Convert.ToInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx) is probably throwing an exception, likely due to being unable to convert the string in your `TextBox` to an integer. `Convert.ToInt32()` can throw the following exceptions (descriptions from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx)):

- `FormatException` - value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9).
- `OverflowException` - value represents a number that is less than Int32.MinValue or greater than Int32.MaxValue.

It's likely a `FormatException`, thrown when you leave the `TextBox` after the `$` is prepended to your string, or after you enter any non-numeric characters (letters, etc). To fix this, you have a couple of options:

- Add a [`try` / `catch` block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) around your code to handle any exceptions.
- Use [`Int32.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`.
- Add some code that will prevent non-numeric characters from being entered in your `TextBox`

Here's an improved version of your event handler:

```
private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string toParse = txtAmount.Text.TrimStart('$');

    int parsed;
    if (Int32.TryParse(toParse, out parsed))
    {
        double res = (double)parsed / 100;
        txtAmount.Text = "$" + res.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be good but if i give the amount initially 500 it was converting to $5 if i came back and leave again it is converting to $0.05

Comment: Well, what are you trying to get it to do? The code you originally wrote was trying to divide the value by 100 each time the TextBox lost focus, is this the intended behavior? If not, what is it?

Comment: good point about dividing by 100.  I assumed the OP was trying to round to a whole number, but now I'm not sure what the actual goal is...

Comment: @adrift Mmhmm. I think the OP needs to rethink a little bit exactly what he's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

The first time you leave this textbox, its contents will be changed to "$123" (for example).  The second time you leave, trying to convert that to int will throw an exception.

You could use the overload of [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) that takes a `NumberStyle`, something like this, assuming your goal is to just show a currency value with no decimal places.

```
double number;

if (double.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out number))
{
    txtAmount.Text = number.ToString("C0");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not convert.");
}
```

After reading @Donut's comment on his answer, I am not sure what your goal is.  If you'd like to truncate the cents off but still show the ".00", you can do this:

```
txtAmount.Text = ((int)number).ToString("C");
```

Or do this, which will round:

```
txtAmount.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(number)).ToString("C");
```

If this does not help, please clarify and let us know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok so inorder to overcome this what i ahve to do

Comment: @Dorababu, can you give examples of what you want to be displayed?  For example, if `txtAmount.Text` is `123.99`, what do you want it changed to:  `$123.99`, `$123.00`, `$124.00`, `$124`, or something else?

Comment: I will be as it is no conversion will be made for those if only a plain amount is given then i will convert it to $ value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAmount.Text) && txtAmount.Text.StartsWith("$"))
        txtAmount.Text = txtAmount.Text.Substring(1);

    int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
    double res = (double)x / 100;

    txtAmount.Text = "$" + res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This also throws an error when i move to and fro for multiple times as Input string was not in correct format and even skipping as i said

Answer (score 0):

Check the txtAmount.Text for the $ sign, before trying to convert it to an int. If the $ sign is present, strip it out, and convert the rest of the input to an int.

Also, you might want to use the **Int32.TryParse** method, as that will help you figuring out whether the entered text can be converted into an int or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change your code to remove the $ before working with the number:

```
private void txtAmount_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int x = 0;
   int.TryParse(txtAmount.Text.Replace("$", string.Empty), out x);
   double res = (double)x / 100;
   txtAmount.Text = "$" + res.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @dorababu: Sorry about that...I edited my answer to remove the error.